# laravel api test always returning status code 500

Tags: laravel, phpunit

i've tried to make this simple test on laravel

```
public function testCrearDuenio()
{
    $response = $this->postJson('api/duenio/registrar',
     [
         'nombre' => 'Pedro',
         'apellido' => 'Rodriguez',
         'ci' => 8167295,
         'celular' => 72635912,
         'correo' => 'prud@gmail.com',
         'contrasenia' => '123',
         'tipousuario' => 1,
         'direccion' => 'Achumani calle 22',
         'ocupacion' => 'Ing. Civil'              
     ]);   

     $response
     ->assertStatus(200);
}
```

but i always get this result

1) Tests\Feature\DuenioModuleTest::testCrearDuenio
Expected status code 200 but received 500.
Failed asserting that false is true.

i've already test this route with postman and it works fine, i think maybe it's a configuration problem

Comment: Errors should be written to `storage/logs/laravel.log`. Could you add the error to your post?

Comment: thanks , i found the error  "no such table: tipousuario" because is a foreign key so before i test the route i seed the table, now its working.